# How do I find the image $y=x$ under mapping $w=z^2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, matrices, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How do I find the image $y=x$  under mapping $w=z^2$ ? Also, how do I graph the image?

Comment: $u+iv=(x+ix)^2=2ix^2$

Answer (score 1):

Exacly like myGlasses suggests in his comment. Parametrize the domain as: $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:y=x\}$ as $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:z=x+xi\}$ and calculate the image as: $u+iv=(x+xi)^2=2ix^2$.

This will place your line on the $y$ axis. Because the image is an even and non-negative function of $x$, you will get a stretched wrap around 0. Here's some Maple code to see the map:

> restart; w := proc (z) options operator, arrow; z^2 end proc;
>   with(plots);
>   complexplot({x+I*x, w(x+I*x)}, x = -1 .. 1, scaling = constrained);

[image]